# How was the market price established in the time of the gemoro?

Tags: transactions, lending-interest-ribbis, bava-metzia

[Rambam - Malveh veLoveh - Chapter 9](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam_cdo/jewish/Rambam.htm) paskens

> א. אין פוסקין על הפירות עד שיצא השער An order for produce cannot be
>   placed until a market price has been established.

according to the mishnah in [Baba Mezi'a 72b](http://www.come-and-hear.com/babamezia/babamezia_72.html).

In the time of the gemoro, how would the parties to a sale know that the market price was established?

Comment: It sounds like a Walrasian auction.

Comment: Fmv............